# Symfony 1.4 - are forms always in <table>?

Tags: forms, html-table, symfony1, customization, semantics

I'm using sfDoctrineAllowPlugin. I need form which has Twitter's Bootstrap semantics. I looked into template and I found, that there is only `$form`, which is a `<table>`. How can I format it in my way? I don't want to use table, rows and cols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [plenty of `render*` functions available](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_customizing_the_form_display) to display each item in your form.

- renderRow
- renderLabel
- render
- renderError
- etc ...

But you can also define a decorator (a custom `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter`) for your form to define the way each item will be display. Check [this example](http://bluehorn.co.nz/2009/08/31/symfony-12-sfform-formatter-to-add-stars-on-required-fields/) of adding * for each required field.