# Symfony 1.4 embedded form fields at the same indent

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have two models in my Symfony application. First one is Blog:

```
Blog:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(20), notnull: true, unique: true }
    title: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    admin_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: admin_id
      ...
```

As you can see this model has a one-to-one relationship with sfGuardUser. I want the registration of these two take place in one form.

So I changed the BlogForm class and used `embeddedRelation` method in it. So two forms just appear together. The problem is their view! User registration form (which is embedded in BlogForm) seems like child! I don't want this... I want the fields be at the same indent.

My form view is like this:

[image: My Current View]

But I want something like this:

[image]

What is the best way to do this? Does it relate to FormFormatter?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085965/removing-table-headers-from-embedrelation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter` or [render* method](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_customizing_the_form_display) ?

I gave an answer for something almost related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109508/569101). And I think it's almost the same problem that came here: [Removing table headers from embedRelation()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085965/removing-table-headers-from-embedrelation)

I think the best way is to manually build the form in the template using `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter` or render* method.

---

**Edit:**

Regarding what I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11163364/569101), try to add a custom formatter like this (in `lib/widget/sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterAc2009.class.php`) :

```
class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterAc2009 extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{
  protected
    // this will remove table around the embed element
    $decoratorFormat = "%content%";

  public function generateLabel($name, $attributes = array())
  {
    $labelName = $this->generateLabelName($name);

    if (false === $labelName)
    {
      return '';
    }

    // widget name are usually in lower case. Only embed form have the first character in upper case
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $name))
    {
      // do not display label
      return ;
    }
    else
    {
      return $this->widgetSchema->renderContentTag('label', $labelName, $attributes);
    }
  }
}
```

Then add it to your form in `ProjectConfiguration`:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    // ...

    sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('ac2009');
  }
}
```

(information comes from [sf website](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_custom_styling_when_a_form_element_has_an_error))

If this doesn't work, please add a `var_dump($name);` before the `if (preg_match` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't want to do it manually. By the way, in FormFormatter, how is it possible to prevent echoing header of the embedded form?

Comment: I have no idea otherwise I would have answered differently :)